# Devexpress winform Autogenerate columns

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol, autogeneratecolumn

Please help me on how to access **AutoGenerateColumns** property of `GridControl` in devexpress just like  `datagridview` in normal control of `winform`.

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q306698 this should help you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to do this

```
gridview1.OptionsBehavior.AutoPopuplateColumns = false;
```

See this for details [AutoPopulateColumns](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q306698)